# Why don't iterators depend on allocators? (i.e. does't making iterators SCARY violate the allocator's typedef abstractions?)

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, iterator

When reading about SCARY iterators in C++11, [I see](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/04/06/10291485.aspx):

> From a compiler perspective there is nothing wrong here. From a practical standpoint, however, there isn’t any semantic dependence between list iterators and list allocators.  And, in general for all STL containers, **iterators only depend (semantically speaking) on the container element type**.

There's something I don't understand about that though:

Iterators return `reference` and `pointer` types when `operator *` or `operator->` is applied to them.
`reference`, `pointer`, `difference_type`, etc. are derived from the `typedef`s inside the **allocator**.

But the allocator *doesn't* necessarily have to define `pointer` as `value_type *` (or even `difference_type` as `ptrdiff_t`), for example.

*How can an iterator (a SCARY one) possibly know what data type(s) to return without knowing the allocator?*

#### Don't iterators inherently depend on their allocators for these typedefs?

Comment: Why would `pointer` and `value_type` be derived from the allocator and not the template parameter itself? Don't you have the dependencies backwards?

Comment: @MarkRansom: *which* template parameter itself are you referring to? The data type `T`?

Comment: Yes, sorry I was ambiguous with my comment.

Comment: @MarkRansom: `vector::pointer` is derived from `allocator::pointer` though, which means `VectorIterator::pointer` must be derived from `vector::pointer`, or in other words, indirectly from `allocator::pointer`. I don't think there's anything that requires `pointer` to be `value_type *` for all allocators. Otherwise the typedef would be completely pointless (no pun intended).

Comment: @Mehrdad: Currently most allocators would have the same typedef's for those types (and the allocator does not even need to provide the type, as there is a default in `allocator_traits`). Whenever that is the case, the iterator type can be the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Allocators were initially designed to provide an interface into the memory model of the platform for which the program was compiling. Most current architectures (if not all) provide a flat memory model, and a single pointer type can be used to address memory in any program (no need for near and far pointers anymore).

That is reflected in C++11 in `allocator_traits`. Now it is not *mandatory* for an allocator to provide many of the typedefs that were previously required, including `pointer_type` or `reference_type`, `difference_type` and so on as there is a known good default value. This really maps to current practice, in most STL implementations those types are the same in all allocators.

Whenever the allocator does not provide the typedefs or the types are the same as the default value provided in `allocator_traits` there is no point in differentiating the iterators based on what allocator was used to construct the container. Where that assumption does not hold, the implementation could determine to use a different iterator type *only* for those allocators that provide a different set of typedefs than the default.

Note that I have not looked at their implementation, so take this at face value: that would support the intended purpose (minimize the generated code without breaking standard compliance).

Also note that this is not the only approach. The current allocator model in C++11 supports the use of polymorphic allocators, even if the standard does not yet provide an implementation. With [polymorphic allocators](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3525.pdf) a single allocator template argument (a polymorphic adaptor) provides the typedefs and the interface with the container, internally managing a pointer to a real allocator used to provide the memory.

The purpose of polymorphic allocators is the same as the paper referred by in the linked article: allow the creation of *vocabulary types*. Where the *SCARY* allocators focus on providing a vocabulary type for the iteration over a particular container type, polymorphic allocators go one step further and enable the use of the container itself as a vocabulary type, regardless of what the actual mechanism to acquire memory is.

You can find a reference implementation of polymorphic allocators (using different names) in Bloomberg's [BSL](https://github.com/bloomberg/bsl)

Comment: Ooh... are SCARY iterators an "optional" thing? I was under the impression that types like `vector` were required to have SCARY iterators... if not then that would answer my question.

Comment: @Mehrdad: I don't really know, but if you *need* to comply with the standard, you must follow the rules of the language. You can probably test this if you have access to that toolchain. Create an allocator that defines a different `pointer_type`, `reference_type`… then compare if the types `std::vector<int>::iterator` and `std::vector<int,yourallocator>::iterator` are exactly the same type.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Nope, SCARY iterators are not required. I think they're recommended, but that is all.

Comment: @Xeo: Interesting. Weren't they always optional though? And how are you supposed to use them in your code? (Doesn't that mean they're nonportable?)

Comment: @Mehrdad: Yes, they're inherently non-portable, as they're not required - you'll have to consult your implementations' documentation (MSVC for one has them).

Comment: @Xeo: Is see. What exactly changed in C++11 regarding SCARY iterators, if anything?

Comment: @Mehrdad: I don't think anything specifically changed. There just was a paper on SCARY iterators, and some implementations decided to adopt it.

Comment: @Mehrdad: As far as I see it, that is just an implementation detail you should not even care about. You might hit it if you inadvertently assign from the wrong container, but that would be a bug in your program. Note that in some implementations back in the day `std::vector<T>::iterator` was just `pointer_type`, which complies with the rules in that paper: same iterator type regardless of the allocator type (as long as the allocator `pointer_type` was the same)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Right, it makes total sense if they're optional. I just thought it's a required thing so I thought it violates the abstractions provided by the typedefs.